# Best practice to store array-like data in MySQL or similar database?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, xml

I have two tables that I want to relate to each other. The issue is any product can have n-number of POs, so individual columns wouldn't work in a traditional DB.

I was thinking of using JSON fields to store an array, or using XML. I would need to insert additional POs, so I'm concerned with the lack of editing support for XML.

What is the standard way of handling n-number of attributes in a single field?

```
|id | Product | Work POs|
| - | ------- | ------- |
| 1 | bicycle | 002,003 |
| 2 | unicycle| 001,003 |

|PO |      Job         |
|-- | ---------------- |
|001|Install 1 wheel   |
|002|Install 2 wheels  |
|003|Install 2 seats   |
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to store multi-valued attributes in a relational database is to create another table, so you can store one value per row. This makes it easy to add or remove one new value, or to search for a specific value, or to count PO's per product, and many other types of queries.

| id | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bicycle |
| 2 | unicycle |

| product_id | PO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 002 |
| 1 | 003 |
| 2 | 001 |
| 2 | 003 |

| PO | Job |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Install 1 wheel |
| 002 | Install 2 wheels |
| 003 | Install seat |

I also recommend reading my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: This is perfect, I was way over thinking this. Another quick question: if I needed to reflect multiple work orders for each product, would I just want to add a quantity column on the new table?

Comment: Yes, you could add other attribute columns to the middle table. Like the date of the PO, or the payer, or the number of work orders. But if any of those is itself a multi-valued attribute (like each work order having attributes for example), you may have to create further tables.

Answer (score 0):

In some case you really need store array-like data in one field.
In MySQL 5.7.8+ you can use JSON type datafield:

```
ALTER TABLE `some_table` ADD `po` JSON NOT NULL`;
UPDATE `some_table` SET `po` = '[002,003]' WHERE `some_table`.`id` = 1;
```

See examples here: https://sebhastian.com/mysql-array/